# Is it possible to add a symbol to the character palette?

Tags: macos, font, internationalization, unicode

I guess everybody here knows about the character palette of Mac OS X.

[image]

Is it possible to create a new symbol, using an image or a vectorial shape made in Illustrator, and add it to the character palette? If so, a brief outline of how this would work would be ideal since I'd like to actually do this to extend my Mac's usable characters with some custom designs.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The character palette simply gives you access to the characters in the fonts on your system.  To add something to it, you need to create a font with that character in it or add the character to an existing font.  Common font creation tools for OS X are Fontlab and Fontforge.  There are also some online services that may work (use Google to find them).